# Partition array in two parts(some elements can be left alone) such that sum of both part is maximum

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am learning dynamic programming from some days. After some practice I saw a problem, which I think can be solved using dynamic programming. The problem is described below :

> You have to place an electronic banner of a company as high as it can be, so that whole the city can 
>       view the banner standing on top of TWO PILLARS.The height of two pillars are to be chosen from given 
>       array. We have to maximize the height of the two pillars standing side by side, so that the pillars 
>       are of EQUAL HEIGHT and banner can be placed on top of it.
>
> Example #1: Input : {1,2,3,4,6}, output : arr1:{1,3,4}, arr2: {6,2}
>   Example #2: Input : {1,2,3,4,5}, output : arr1:{3,4}, arr2: {2,5}

I thought this problem like either I will include any element in set 1 or set 2 or none of the set, then choose max of all the 3. Its looks like there is optimal substructure. But I am not sure how to store results and use them in future. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like NP Hard problem

Comment: I was thinking one solution is do BFS traversal for every element and every step 3 possible paths are there. Explore every path. But its complexity would be 3^n. I was thinking if there any better approach exists or not.

Comment: In your first input: ```{1,2,3,4,6}``` isn't ```{1,3,4}``` and ```{2,6}``` the solution ?

Comment: @grodzi Yes I have corrected it.

Comment: @ruakh Yes. it is the same problem. I was not aware that it is NP hard problem.